# Create a simple timed Java quiz

Tags: java, random, timer

I'm writing a simple java program to ask random math questions. I'm just using the console so nothing fancy.

How can I time how long it takes the user to answer a question from when it is first asked to when they key in an answer and hit return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the time in milliseconds before and after each question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062345/measuring-time-differences-using-system-currenttimemillis

Comment: @Aro This question is about timing how long it takes a human to answer a question. If you're suggesting using `System.nanoTime()` for that, I think it would be serious overkill.

Comment: My code works with System.nanoTime() but when I use System.currentTimeMillis() I keep coming up with a difference of '0'. I'm not entirely sure why...and that's probably beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a date to save the time when the question was displayed for the first time.

```
import java.util.Date;

Date startDate = new Date();
```

Then after the answer was submitted, subtract the date from the current time

```
long totalMilliseconds = (new Date()).getTime() - startDate.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply save the date when the question is shown

```
Date start = new Date();
```

Do the same when an answer is received and then calculate the difference and parse it to seconds or minutes:

```
long diff = start.getTime() - end.getTime();
long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;  
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
```